# Test suite failed to run using @mui/x-data-grid

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

I am using @mui-x-data-grid in my React component

I have written a test file which is using the above component.

But test fails when deployed to higher env (Works in local)

Below is the error.

**Test suite failed to run
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(\p{L}|\p{M}\p{L}|\p{M}|\p{N}|\p{Z}|\p{S}|\p{P})$/: Invalid escape
at Object. (node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/index-cjs.js:15:41734)**

When I check the node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/index-cjs.js file , it has a regular expression in it.

How can I fix this issue?

I am using -
"@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.2.0",

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: did you find a solution?